# Transposing rows to single column by group pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone help me with this transformation. I have a dataset:

| ID | a1 | a2 | a3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 5 | 3 |
| a | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| b | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| b | 3 | 5 | 6 |
| c | 5 | 1 | 3 |
| c | 2 | 4 | 2 |

and i want it like this:

| ID | Levels |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 5 |
| a | 3 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| b | 5 |
| b | 3 |
| b | 5 |
| b | 6 |

..... and so forth.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 'melt' function:

```
df_melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], var_name='Levels', value_name='Values')
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
df.set_index('ID').stack().droplevel(1).reset_index(name='Levels')
```

Output:

```
   ID  Levels
0   a       1
1   a       5
2   a       3
3   a       2
4   a       3
5   a       3
6   b       2
7   b       3
8   b       5
9   b       3
10  b       5
11  b       6
12  c       5
13  c       1
14  c       3
15  c       2
16  c       4
17  c       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.MultiIndex`

```
names = ["ID", "Levels"]
data = <your data>

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(i) for i in data.shape], names=names)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)
```